# CGI Upload Script in Perl

Tags: perl, http, upload, cgi

I have a cgi script for upload which is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $cgi = new CGI;
my $file = $cgi->param('file');
$file=~m/^.*(\\|\/)(.*)/; # strip the remote path and keep the filename
my $name = $2;
open(LOCAL, ">/home/Desktop/$name") or die $!;

while(<$file>) {
  $data .= $_;
}
print $cgi->header();
print "$file has been successfully uploaded... thank you.\n";
    print $data;
```

The HTML file is as follows

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.cgi" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
            Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting a weird error now..

> Software error:
>
> Is a directory at htdocs/upload.cgi line 9.
>
> For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely the case that the path specified in the open

```
open(LOCAL, ">/home/Desktop/$name") or die $!;
```

is pointing to a directory.  This may be because `$name` is empty (and thus `/home/Desktop/` *is* a directory) or the target name is a directory underneath the Desktop.

I'd have to think about it more, and try to be nefarious, but I'm fairly sure that there are ways of specifying paths outside the path that you are intending allowing someone who is being nefarious to upload files in places you don't expect them to be.

Comment: Is that possible to use `chroot` to prevent from malicious actions outside of the desired directory?

Comment: @jingyu It would be a step in the right direction, though you still get into some dangerous possibilities with this upload location ("/home/Desktop") - writing to a user space.  Someone could overwrite a file in the directory, create a file that *looks* like, say, your hard drive that is malware, etc...